# Preventing RTE from removing scripts for specific templates only

Tags: richtext-editor

I need to prevent Sitecore from removing my script tags in RTE for specific templates even when `HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts` is `true`.

I have looked at 
https://laubplusco.net/customizing-sitecore-rich-text-field-configuration/
https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/ever-wished-the-rich-text-field-didnt-mess-with-your-html/

but both didn't work, I'm not sure if this is related to the articles being old or I'm doing something wrong.

Setting `HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts` value to `false` works, but when I use the below when the setting value is `true` it doesn't:

```
base.SetupFilters();
base.Editor.DisableFilter(EditorFilters.RemoveScripts);
```

using Sitecore 8.2 u 7

Comment: Instead of programatically trying to enable/disable this setting, I would add a `Multi-line Text` field to those templates to allow you to add script tags to (my first choice would be to handle this differently and avoid specifying JS files like this at all)

Comment: Thanks. I actually agree with you and we have already used `Multi-line Text` to supply js sources. But the customer is pushing to allow js in RTE!!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the above links (in the question) do not work anymore. Any inline js is removed on several levels and so it's extremely difficult to handle all of them without making your upgrade process a nightmare!

However I managed to find a workaround, by reversing the logic:

1. Set the `HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts` value to false. So js is never removed
2. Use one of the links above (in the question) to override `Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorConfiguration` and add your logic to always enable the `RemoveScripts` filter (which removes inline js) except for certain templates to keep the filter disabled.

This workaround has the downside of having the `HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts` setting value as `false`, however Sitecore would function as if it was `true`.